# Inequality proof problem

Tags: algebra-precalculus, inequality, ceiling-and-floor-functions

How can I prove that there always exists an integer $x$ such that $2a\geq2^x-1\geq a$ for all positive integers $a$?

Comment: That would be $x=\lfloor \log_2 a \rfloor+1$

Comment: Could you elaborate?

Comment: ChennaiSuperkings, I elaborated as an answer

Answer (score 0):

$x=\lfloor \log_2 a \rfloor+1$ is the integer that satisfies the hypothesis, because:

$$2^x = 2^{\lfloor \log_2 a \rfloor+1}> 2^{\log_2 a}=a$$

and

$$2^x = 2^{\lfloor \log_2 a \rfloor+1}\leq 2^{\log_2 a+1}=2\cdot 2^{\log_2 a}=2a$$

$\lfloor y \rfloor$ stands for the floor function, which has the property $\lfloor y \rfloor  \leq y < \lfloor y \rfloor +1$.

Comment: In this you have proved that $2a\geq 2^x>a$ instead of $2a\geq 2^x-1>a$. Is it possible to prove that $2a\geq 2^x-1>a$?

Comment: @ChennaiSuperkings , In your question you ask for $2x−1\geq a$, not $2x−1>a$ (in which case the question would not be true anymore for $a=1$). Note that what I proved $2a\geq 2^x>a$ implies your question almost trivially because:

 $$1)\ 2a \geq 2^x > 2^x-1 \implies 2a \geq 2^x-1$$
 $$2)\ 2^x>a \implies 2^x-1 \geq a \text{ (since we are talking about integers)}$$ 

There for $2a \geq 2^x -1 \geq a$. If you need other clarifications let me know.